# Yii2 Swiftmailer foreach sending same email to first to

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I am trying to send emails by swiftmailer in foreach. But it always sends only to first email addressee times number of users. (say, there are 3 users, it will send 3 mails to first user).
I have checked that every iteration of sendmail have different email address, that address is in $email instance ($email->getTo()) and as long as it cannot send email (ie. on localhost) it works fine. It creates 3 emails, with 3 different addresses. But when it actually can send it via SMTP it will send all mails to same person with same text rendered.

I am thinking that issue is with $app->mailer->compose, but i am not really sure. (seems like that instance is holding its data and it cannot be rewritten, till app resets)

Controller:

```
foreach ($invitations as $invitation_id) {
            $model = Invitation::findOne($invitation_id);
            if (!empty($model)) {
                if (!$model->sendMail('Test mail')) {
                    $errors[] = $model->userName;
                }
            } else {
                $errors[] = "Non existing $invitation_id?";
            }
        }
```

Model Invitation:

```
public function sendMail ($text){
    $user = User::findOne($this->user_id);
    $email = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('layouts/bulk-email', ['user' => $user, 'text' => $text])
        ->setFrom('test@test.com')
        ->setTo($user['mail'])
        ->setSubject('Test subject');
    return $email->send();
    }
```

I tried using the sendMultiple method (creating messages first to array, and then send them all at once), but instead they were all send 6 times to first address.

Is there something obvious i am missing?

Comment: you need to pass the `user_id` to the `sendMail()` along with the subject, you are using `$this->user_id` which send the email to the emal in the current instance.

Comment: Yea sorry, sendMail is method in model Invitation, and that foreach is in controller. That's not really the issue - as i stated above the code, i tried to get the mail address from Swiftmailer object and it is correct. But it doesnt change the fact it is still sent to first user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual issue was that localhost is not caching ldap answers, but the dev server is. So the issue was actually what Muhammad Omer Aslam somewhat suggested :)